# Wordpress page url re-write with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

In my existing wordpress site I have a page set-up with a custom template file for the specific page. Wordpress permalink rewrite for this page as per the slug  /at/

We then use some extra variables to get different data on this page

http://websitename.com/at/?h=s3fgh

and would like to now re-write this url with htaccess to something like this

http://websitename.com/at/s3fgh

But can't seem to make it work. At the moment I've tried to amend the htaccess file but without prefered results

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^at/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$  /index.php?page_id=113&h=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

where 113 equals the specific page id

Answer (score 1):

You may try replacing the complete rule-set in your question with this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Add this line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !/at/  [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# /at/ folder rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !index\.php                [NC]
RewriteRule ^at/([^/]+)/?   /index.php?page_id=113&h=$1 [NC,L]
```

Last rule maps silently this requested URL:

`http://websitename.com/at/anything`

to this one, according to the rule in the question:

`http://websitename.com/index.php?page_id=113&h=anything`

#### OPTION

This option is needed because the question says one thing and the rules included in that same question (**?**) show other thing. Let's stick to the examples in the question this time.

Replace the 3 last lines in the above rule-set with these ones:

```
# /at/ folder rule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !h=        [NC]
RewriteRule ^at/([^/]+)/?   /at/?h=$1  [NC,L]
```

Maps silently this requested URL:

`http://websitename.com/at/anything`

to this one, according to the URL examples in the question:

`http://websitename.com/at/?h=anything`